# Can't access url params, passed using react-router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm having issues accessing a parameter called **bookId** from the **Reader.js** component. The parameter is passed down from **BookCarouselItem.js** using react-router. **Reader.js** is a connected component.

I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but does react-router work with redux connected components? Or do I need to use something like [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)?

I've tried to refer to similar questions but wasn't able to find a solution, help would be greatly appreciated.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { routes } from 'constants/index';
import Reader from 'components/reader/Reader'


Class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid main-container'>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Route
                            path={'/reader/:bookId'}
                            component={() => <Reader />}
                        />
                    </div>    
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

BookCarouselItem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export class BookCarouselItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { bookThumbnail } = this.props;
        const { name, numberOfSections } = bookThumbnail;
        const bookId = 0;

        return (
            <Link className='book-carousel-link' to={`/reader/${bookId}`}>
                    <div className='book-info-overlay'>
                        <h5>{name}</h5>
                        <span>{numberOfSections} Sections</span>
                    </div>
            </Link>
        );
    }
}

export default BookCarouselItem;
```

Reader.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

export class Reader extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const { match, pageLevel } = this.props;
            console.log(match); // undefined

        return (
            <div>
                <div className='reader-body'>         
                        <Book bookId={match.params.bookId} 
                              pageLevel={pageLevel}
                              bank={bank}/>

                </div>

        );
    }
}

Const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        metadata: state.book.metadata,
        pageLevel: state.book.pageLevel  
    }
};

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default compose(
    withAuthorization(authCondition),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(Reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the component to the `component` prop and the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) will be passed down to the component automatically.

```
<Route
  path="/reader/:bookId"
  component={Reader}
/>
```

If you want to render something that is not just a component, you have to pass down the route props manually.

```
<Route
  path="/reader/:bookId"
  render={props => <Reader {...props} />}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately neither of those worked. Still stumped.

Comment: @PashaPear That's frustrating. Does it work if you wrap the export from the Reader.js file with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)? `export default withRouter(compose(...));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but **maybe** `mapStateToProps` rewrite you props so could you please first read [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/324#issuecomment-199452669)